# Actualizar tabla msql con formulario PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una base de datos que contiene una tabla con los valores de un usuario que los voy registrando mediante un formulario, pero también tengo esta tabla con la que necesito actualizar esos mismos campos.
pero no logra modificar los datos mediante el metodo POST.

Dejo el codigo aquí del formulario que contiene inputs los cuales los estoy llamando mediante el metodo post.

```
<?php require_once('../conexion.php'); ?>

<?php if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start(); ?>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['registrar']) && $_POST['registrar']=="Actualizar"){
    $query="UPDATE registro SET nombre='$_POST[nombre]', email='$_POST[email]', telefono ='$_POST[telefono]',
    direccion='$_POST[direccion]' WHERE `id` = '$_POST[id]'";
     $conn->query($query);
     if ($conn) {
              echo "Sus datos han sido modificados exitosamente";

     } else{
         echo "No se han modificado sus datos";
     }

}?>

<?php include("cabecera.php"); ?>

<body>
    <!--incluimos menu principal -->
    <?php include("menu.php"); ?>
    <section class="mt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST" action="">

                <h2>Actualizar Usuario</h2>
                <label for="nombre">Ingresar Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                <label for="email">Ingresa tu Correo Eletrónico</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                <label for="telefono">Ingresa tu Teléfono</label>
                <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono">
                <label for="pais">Seleccione su país</label>
                <select name="pais" id="pais">
                    <option>--Seleccion Pais --</option>
                    <option value="argentina">Argentina</option>
                    <option value="brasil">Brasil</option>
                    <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
                    <option value="chile">Chile</option>
                </select>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Ingresar dirección</label>
                    <textarea name="direccion" id="direccion" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>

                <input name="id" type="hidden" value="Actualizar" />
                <input type="submit" name="registrar" id="registrar" value="Actualizar"/>


            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- incluimos el footer -->
    <?php include("pie.php")?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué hace el código: da error, qué error, muestra algún mensaje, qué mensaje?  Ya de paso, dinos si usas PDO o mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El origen del problema está en esta línea:

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="Actualizar"/>
```

Que debería tener en el atributo `value` el `id` del registro a modificar.

Suponiendo que tu tabla tenga esta estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE registro(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(31),
  email varchar(31),
  telefono varchar(31),
  direccion varchar(31),
  pais varchar(31)
  );
```

Y ya cuente con este dato:

```
INSERT INTO registro (nombre) VALUES ('Manolo');
```

Modificando el formulario en HTML con:

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

Y retocando un poco el PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['registrar']) && $_POST['registrar']=="Actualizar"){
    $query="
        UPDATE registro SET 
            nombre='$_POST[nombre]',
            email='$_POST[email]',
            telefono ='$_POST[telefono]',
            direccion='$_POST[direccion]',
            pais='$_POST[pais]'
            WHERE `id` = '$_POST[id]';
    ";
    $conn->query($query);
     if ($conn->affected_rows)
        echo "Sus datos han sido modificados exitosamente";
     else
        echo "No se han modificado sus datos";
```

Debería funcionar como esperas. Simplemente he añadido `pais` y he realizado la comprobación de campos modificados con la propiedad `affected_rows` pues, el `$conn`, si no hay ningún error de conexión a la base de datos, siempre te va a decir que ha modificado lo datos correctamente.

Solamente te queda un detalle por pulir: ¿cómo sabes el `id`? Si dejas en el HTML un `1` siempre te va a modificar el primer registro de la tabla. Entiendo que ese formulario saque los datos de la propia base de datos para no modificar todos los campos desde cero. Por lo que deberías hacer uso del atributo `values` en cada campo, tras leer todos los datos de la base de datos. Algo así:

```
$r=$conn->query("
    SELECT * FROM registro WHERE id=1;
")->fetch_assoc();
```

Y, en cada campo:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" 
    placeholder="Nombre" 
    value="<?=$r['nombre']?>"
>
```

Pero ten en cuenta el `id=1` sigue siendo un valor fijo, ese `id` podría venirte de un enlace que cuelgues de un listado, por ejemplo:

```
<a href="?id=1">Modificar</a>
```

Para después utilizarlo así:

```
$r=$conn->query("
    SELECT * FROM registro WHERE id=".($_GET['id']*1).";
")->fetch_assoc();
```

Bueno, deja tus dudas por los comentarios para concretar la respuesta, que tampoco quiero divagar demasiado. A ver si lo que querías era hacer un `INSERT` y estamos dándole vueltas de más al `UPDATE`.

Answer (score -1):

Hola Intenta cambiando la cadena de query de la siguiente forma:

```
$query="UPDATE registro SET nombre='".$_POST['nombre']."', email='".$_POST['email']."', telefono ='".$_POST['telefono']."', direccion='".$_POST['direccion']."' WHERE `id` = '".$_POST['id']."'";
```

Lo que sucede es que el POST es un array y no puedes concatenar directamente

Comment: Lo que OP hace en ese sentido es válido, si la cadena está rodeada por comillas dobles puedes perfectamente usar las claves del array sin comillas de ningún tipo, basta que hagas la prueba con un array cualquiera. El problema por tanto no es ese.